# Branchless Fizbuzz in Posix C (no if-s, ternaries, switches or loops)

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

Yesterday when I was showering I was thinking of branchless programming and a thought occurred to me, whether it's possible to write a branchless solution of the Fizbuzz problem. The constraints I put on myself were no if statements, no switches, no ternary operators and no loops.
The code below seems to solve this problem as well as test the first 100 numbers:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

jmp_buf buf;

int jump(jmp_buf buf)
{
  longjmp(buf, 1);
}

int wrapexit()
{
  exit(0);
}

void fizbuzz(int num)
{
  char str[5];
  sprintf(str, "%d\n", num);
  (num % 3 && num % 5) &&  write(0, str, 5);
  write(0, "fizbuzz\n", strlen("fizbuzz\n") * !(num % 15)) && jump(buf);
  write(0, "buzz\n", strlen("buzz\n") * !(num % 5)) && jump(buf);
  write(0, "fiz\n", strlen("fiz\n") * !(num % 3));
}

int test(int num)
{
  int throaway = (num == 101 && wrapexit());
  fizbuzz(num);
  int status = setjmp(buf);
  status && test(num + 2);
  !status && test(num + 1);
  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  test(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Also, I know I'm not doing any buffer length checks when I'm stringizing `num` at the beginning of `fizbuzz`. Anyway, code reviews most welcome.

Comment: "Branchless Fizbuzz"?? `(num % 3 && num % 5) &&  write(0, str, 5);` looks like branching code to me with its `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you do an `&& function(...)`, you have a conditional branch. One might even, with good reason, count function calls as branches as well. And `setjmp()` is usually implemented by changing the stack pointer and then calling a `ret` instruction or something similar, which in effect is also a branch.

The closest you can come to having a "branchless" fizbuzz in C is by unrolling the loop and writing 15 lines at a time:

```
void fizbuzz(int num) {
    printf("%d\n", num++);
    printf("%d\n", num++);
    printf("fiz\n"); num++;
    printf("%d\n", num++);
    printf("buzz\n"); num++;
    printf("fiz\n"); num++;
    printf("%d\n", num++);
    printf("%d\n", num++);
    printf("fiz\n"); num++;
    printf("buzz\n"); num++;
    printf("%d\n", num++);
    printf("fiz\n"); num++;
    printf("%d\n", num++);
    printf("%d\n", num++);
    printf("fizbuzz\n"); num++;
    fizbuzz(num); // tail recursion
}
```

It still calls functions, and at the end it will jump back to the beginning. But at least they are all *unconditional* branches.

Comment: Perhaps drop the 15x `num++`, use one long `printf()` and then `fizbuzz(num+15);`?

Comment: You can also have 100 `printf` statements - no recursive loop needed. Or just hard code the results ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't use it, but your restrictions don't seem to exclude it, so if you make use of the `||` operator things can be simplified.

```
void fizbuzz(int num)
{
    !(num % 15) && printf("fizbuzz\n") ||
    !(num % 5) && printf("buzz\n") ||
    !(num % 3) && printf("fiz\n") ||
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Then you don't need to use `setjmp` and can get rid of the `jump` function.

`test` then becomes a smaller 4 line function:

```
int test(int num)
{
    num == 101 && wrapexit();
    fizbuzz(num);
    test(num + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Damn, this is so much better, didn't even think of logical or. And also you're using printf which is unbuffered so that's another plus.

Comment: *buffered, `printf` is buffered, `write` is unbuffered.